# webclient blocking main thread netty, why?

Tags: spring, kotlin, netty, webclient, blocking

I don't understand why webclient blocks the main netty thread
I use gradle here are its dependencies:

```
dependencyManagement {
    imports {
        mavenBom "org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-dependencies:Hoxton.SR11"
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-webflux'
    ...
}
```

This gradle script is used in both applications.
In the first application, I perform:

```
    @GetMapping
    open fun otherApp(): Mono<String> {
        return WebClient.create("http://localhost:8081")
                .get()
                .uri("/test")
                .retrieve()
                .bodyToMono(String::class.java)
//              I tried to use an additional scheduler but the main stream is blocked with it too
//              .publishOn(Schedulers.boundedElastic())
    }
```

The second application emulates a long response processing:

```
@GetMapping("/test")
    open fun test(): Mono<String> {
        Thread.sleep(15000L)
        return Mono.just("Hello");
    }
```

And I expect that the calling service will not block the main thread, but will continue to process incoming connections, but until I get a response from the first call(sleep will work), my next connections are hanging in wait.

Result:
The first application works like tomcat with a single thread

My question:
What do i wrong?

Comment: How do you know the first application is blocked? Do you call application 2 again?

Comment: I call the first application directly in the browser, it hangs on port 8080, and the request hangs, it's ok.
Within 15 seconds, while the second application emulates the processing of the first request, I call the first application again in another browser window and the second request to the first application does not enter the controller

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The client application does not block, it is able to process new requests. You can confirm that by adding logs:

```
@GetMapping("/test")
public Mono<String> test() {
    return Mono.just("incoming request")
        .doOnNext(e -> logger.info("Process: {}", e))
        .flatMap(e -> webclient.test());
}
```

The server application is blocked because `Thread.sleep(15000L)` blocks the main thread (consider using `.delayElement(Duration.ofSeconds(15))` instead)

### If the issue happens for requests originated by a web browser

It is due to the browser cache. You should disable caching or force a hard refresh(CTRL + F5).

I tested the hard refresh and it seems to work fine.

Comment: mmh if I understood the OP correctly these are 2 separate applications, so the `Thread.sleep` cannot block the first application (see the comment below the post)

Comment: Exactly, the server application(the second one) blocks.

Comment: Sorry, apparently you misunderstood me. The client application that I access through the browser is blocked(but it should not), the second application(server) I don't mind that it was blocked, the question is why the client application's webclient blocks the thread

Comment: It is blocked through the browser.

Comment: Try to make 2 simultaneous requests from your browser.  You will get both responses within ~15 secs. This is because client application didn't block, it forwarded both requests to server application immediately.

Comment: Then I wouldn't have created this question) This is exactly the problem if you make 2 requests from the browser, the answer for the second one will be only after ~30 seconds, for example if you use cURL then ~15

Comment: @DonDonovan I have updated my answer.